# Can I run SAS code in a stored process before prompts are asked

Tags: sql, sas

I would like to make a SAS stored process which has a dynamic prompt depending on a table.

Is it possible to make a PROC SQL run after running the stored process but before the prompts are asked, so that the table from which I choose my prompt values would be updated when I run the stored process?

**Or**

Do I have to make two stored processes; one that updates the table and another one which depends on the updated table?

I am using Enterprise Guide to make the stored process.

Comment: You have a dynamic prompt that displays values from a table, or a prompt that displays values from one of a number of tables depending on [something else]?

Comment: I have dynamic prompt that displays values from a table. I would like to run a code that updates the table.

Comment: The prompts are displayed before the STP is run. How can it be possible to make the SQL run after the STP but before the prompts?

Comment: I guess it is not possible to do what I wanted to do then. Thanks

Comment: I don't know how STPs work, but in regular EG, you can set a prompt to run for any specific program inside a process flow; so if I were doing this in regular EG I would set up a process flow with a program updating the table, then a second program that the prompt was assigned to running after that.  Can you do something similar with STPs?  Chain two STPs together?